# codeigniter session doesn't update on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

why is it that codeigniter session doesn't update values when an ajax request is done?

controller index:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata( 'greetings', 'hello!' );
}
```

ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url("set_greeting"); ?>",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        alert('<?= $this->session->userdata('greetings'); ?>');
    }
});
```

controller:

```
public function set_greeting()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata( 'greetings', 'hi!' );
        echo $this->session->userdata('greetings');
    }
```

after the ajax request is made, I've checked firebug's console and the controller's response echoed "hi!" but the alerted value from the success of ajax is still "hello".

Comment: Session has been set need page refresh. Then you will get session set value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is running on server side and all PHP code is rendered before sending anything to the client so  `alert('<?= $this->session->userdata('greetings'); ?>');` is rendered to  `alert('hello');`.

When you do

`success: function(response){
     alert('<?= $this->session->userdata('greetings'); ?>');
}`

it is basically saying to alert `hello` if the ajax request succeeds.

since PHP cannot reflect any changes done on the server side without a page refresh you cannot see changes done to server session but if you refresh the page you will be able to see the changed value because `'<?= $this->session->userdata('greetings'); ?>'` is renderd again on the server and now its value is changed to `hi`.(But in your code you won't be able to see the session change since your index method always set the value to `hello`. Changed value will always overwritten with the page refresh but if you use any other controller method in your system which does not set that particular session value you can reflect the change.)

Why this happens in your code ?

This happens because you're not using the `response` to your ajax request. You're correctly changing the server session and response is also correct but since you're not using the `response` you cannot see the modified value.Use the response and you should be all good.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert('<?= $this->session->userdata('greetings'); ?>');
```

This code will render before your ajax request..

```
alert(response);
```

use this to see your updated session value;

Comment: i thought that line of code should render after a successful ajax request?

Answer (score 2):

No change in index part

```
public function index()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata( 'greetings', 'hello!' );
}
```

I assume that following javascript loaded on `index` page only. See i have changed `alert` part.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo site_url("set_greeting"); ?>",
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response){
     alert(response);
     }
    });
```

For the `set_greeting` handler update as below,

```
public function set_greeting(){

        $this->session->set_userdata( 'greetings', 'hi!' );
        $greetings = $this->session->userdata('greetings');
        $this->output->set_output($greetings); // Note: set output data here.    
    }
```